# Massive number of bad sectors on a hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

I just added a new hard drive to my PC, and have been seeing some strange behavior with it. I'm wondering if they're symptoms of a problem, or if I'm just hitting some glitches for some reason. I should mention that the drive is meant to be for backup, so I'm not concerned with the data on it at the moment. (I'm aware this isn't a "proper" backup solution, I have others for my important stuff, this is just to protect from drive failure).

Anyway, I installed the drive, did a full format (took ~5 hours for a 2TB drive), and then started copying various data to it. After about 1TB had been copied, I happened to open My Computer, and noticed that the drive only had 10 GB of free space left on it, when I expected something in the 800-900 GB range. After checking various things to confirm that only 1TB should have been used, I ran `chkdsk /R` on it, and it came up with **880 GB of bad sectors**.

That just seems ridiculous to me, whenever I've seen bad sectors in the past, it's been a very small number. I've reformatted the drive (just a quick format this time), did a sector scan again (which reported no problems - huh?), and am currently copying to it again to see if the same thing happens. Just thought I'd ask for advice in the meantime, was that an indicator of massive problems with this drive, or could it have been some sort of glitch? Any other tools I should run on it to check?

Windows XP x64 if it matters, thanks.

Comment: There's no need to do a full format on new hard drives anymore. That said, you could try doing a single-pass zero-writing format (with `format X: /fs:ntfs /p:1` to see if it does the same thing again.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1218312/pending-sector-issue-does-this-mean-the-hdd-is-failing/1218317#1218317

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to find a drive fitness test from the manufacturer, which you could possibly use any reported error codes to claim warranty replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You should find the manufacturer disk tool, and see if there is something to format it.
If still doesn't work, call them and ask if you can have another hard drive giving back yours.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue before, it was because of PCIe over-clocking the bios, turning that off automagicly fixed the problem.